# coloring primefaces table cells depending on condition

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

it's my first project with primefaces, and I can't find out why my cells are not colored.
my XHTML file contains the following:

```
<h:head>
<title>Job Status Reporter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jobstatusreport/colors.css" />
</h:head>

 ...

 <h:dataTable var="myJob" value="#{workPackage.jobs}"
    rowStyleClass="#{myJob.jobStatus == 'SUCCESS' ? 'green' : 
  (myJob.jobStatus == 'PARTIAL SUCCESS' ? 'yellow' : (myJob.jobStatus == 'FAILURE' ? 'red'   :'white'))}">
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobId}" />
</h:column>
<h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobType}" />
</h:column>
    <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobStatus}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

and my colors.css file is created in WebContent/resources/css/ folder and defined as follow:

```
.green.ui-datatable { background: green;}

.red.ui-datatable {background: red;}

.yellow.ui-datatable {background: yellow;}

.white.ui-datatable {background: white;}
```

but I still get uncolored cells on my web browser, can anyone tell me what's the problem?

EDIT:

when I changed h:dataTable ... to p:dataTable ... I got the following message:

```
/globalReport.xhtml @32,169 rowStyleClass="#{myJob.jobStatus == 'SUCCESS' ? 'green' : (myJob.jobStatus == 'PARTIAL SUCCESS' ? 'yellow' : (myJob.jobStatus == 'FAILURE' ? 'red' : 'white'))}": Property 'jobStatus' not found on type org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$SetProxy
```

can anyone help, please?

Comment: maybe the path to css is wrong, do like this http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/how-to-include-cascading-style-sheets-css-in-jsf/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color the rows of datatable based a condition in JSF 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745017/color-the-rows-of-datatable-based-a-condition-in-jsf-2)

Comment: I already tried it, it doesn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: @Lukasz: please read my xhtml file the proposed solution already is done but not efficient, I get no positive results

Comment: @Djedai40 oh sorry, they are using Tomahawk components, but the rule is the same, h:dataTable doesn't have such attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally found a solution: 
In myJob class I added the below method:

```
    public String createLabel(){

    switch (jobStatus){

    case "SUCCESS":
        return "SUCCESS";

    case "PARTIAL SUCCESS":
        return "PARTIAL_SUCCESS";

    case "FAILURE":
        return "FAILURE";

    default: 
        return "DEFAULT";   
    }
}
```

and in my globalReport.xhtml I changed the following:

```
<h:head>
<title>Job Status Reporter</title>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="colors.css" target="head" />
</h:head> 

....

<h:dataTable var="myJob" value="#{workPackage.jobs}">
    <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobId}"/>
</h:column>
    <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobType}"/>
</h:column>
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{myJob.jobStatus}" styleClass="#{myJob.createLabel()}"/>
</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

and my colors.css is :

```
.SUCCESS{
background-color : green !important;
}

.FAILURE{
background-color: red !important; 
}

.PARTIAL_SUCCESS{
background-color: yellow !important;
}

.DEFAULT{
background-color: white !important; 
}
```

and it works perfectly. many thanks @Lukasz for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

Your situation is similar as [Color the rows of datatable based a condition in JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745017/color-the-rows-of-datatable-based-a-condition-in-jsf-2). `h:dataTable` doesn't have such attribute, since you're using PrimeFaces, you should use their components, since they provide much more functionality.

Use `<p:dataTable rowStyleClass="..." ... />` as well as `<p:column../>` within it.

It would be probably more readable and less error-prone if you'd generate the style class in the item, to prevent too long and complex EL expression.

You may note style differences because components rendered by PrimeFaces are using jQuery-UI CSS styles, but you may customize them as easy as "old" components from "h:" namespace.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice the <h:dataTable>, but it doesn't change anything but it worsens when I changed to <p:dataTable>, now I got the EDITED error message, do you have any idea about this matter?

Comment: @Djedai40 it seems like your enum value, or something similar, not the JSF/PrimeFaces error message. Try the way I've proposed, generate the style class in your bean. Too long EL expressions are hard to debug and have poor performance.

Comment: when I debug in browser I get 404 file not found error, it seems that it can't find the file, is it possible that I'm making mistake in declaring :    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jobstatusreport/colors.css" />

Comment: @Djedai40 `myJob` is something that doesn't have method `getJobStatus`. Why do you have proxies in your collection, I don't know, and it's another question. You should simply debug what getJobs() method is returning...

Comment: Please prevent also chameleon questions. The title is about coloring rows depending on condition, adding other errors will be distracting to future visitors. If 'something' is creating a proxy and debugging won't give you any hint, it's better to create a new question.

Comment: the methods return the correct values because when I ignore coloring the cells I get all pieces of information, and all my getters and setters have been tested. the problem is in loading the css file, but I can't find a way to make it happen.