# Change the color the rows of datatable with a button click

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

Starting from [Color the rows of datatable based a condition in JSF 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745017/color-the-rows-of-datatable-based-a-condition-in-jsf-2):

How would you change this so clicking a button in the row of the datatable changed a value of entry.action and therefore the rowStyleClass? Is there a way to update the rowStyleClass after rendering?

My button is already has a  tag that calls a listener that's changing the value of entry.action.

Comment: You can add an ajax event on the button so that clicking on it triggers the listener for `entry.action` then refreshes you datatable

Comment: My <a4j:ajax> tag contains render="datatable-id". The datatable has rowStyleClass="#{entry.action ? 'altline2' : 'line2'}".